# NServiceBus & Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, microservices, nservicebus

I am working on a project that uses NServiceBus ESB. A microservice "A" send a request to microservice "B" asking for a list of data records (e.g. instructor  records)  stored in the database.
Is there a way in which inside the Handle method we could do some thing like:

```
 List<Instructor> instructors = await _coursecontext.CourseSet
     .Where(x => x.InstructorGuid == instructor.Instructor_Unique_Id)
     .ToListAsync();
```

currently I get the error message that the Handle method must be made async.

Thanks!

I changed the Handle to be async but then ran into problems that Handle is not implemented correctly:

[image: async Task Handle(Command myrequest, IMessageHandlerContext context)]

Comment: Does the `Handle` message comes from the `IHandleMessages` interface?

Comment: Yes. it does:   public class InstructorCoursesReqHandler :
    IHandleMessages<MyReqyest> { ....}

Comment: Can you share a bit more of the actual code, please?

Answer (score 0):

[NServiceBus handlers](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/handlers/) support task-based asynchrony, just add the `async` keyword (which enables the use of `await`) to the implementation :

```
public class MyAsyncHandler : IHandleMessages<MyMessage>
{
    public async Task Handle(MyMessage message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        // do something with the message data
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/)

Comment: I tried this approach:  public async Task Handle(Command message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
 {
     Task reply;
      reply = some code; 
     return reply;
 } . The error is that  can not  do "return reply" .

Comment: @Serdan and what happend? Please share the full code and error text.

Comment: I have an image capture of the exact error message. can I add that in the comment? Thanks.

Comment: @Serdan errors are text so it is better to add them as text. But you can add a link to image if you want. Also you can update your question.

Comment: updated the question with error message. Thanks!

Comment: @Serdan remove the `return ...` if you have any in the method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256696/discussion-between-serdan-and-guru-stron).

Comment: you are trying to return data from message handler to service that sent a message ?